# Is there any way to allow a group of ip in the certain range to access my website?(Nginx)

Tags: nginx, security, ip, ip-address

Suppose, I want to allow access to my project for the IP falling between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.40.

Nginx example:

```
  stream {
        #...
        server {
            listen 12345;
            deny   192.168.1.2;
            allow  192.168.1.1/24;
            allow  2001:0db8::/32;
            deny   all;
        }
    }
```

I have to allow each and every IP separately or is there any technique that will allow access to the ip falling in the given range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allow` and `deny` statements are evaluated in order, until a match is found, so you could impose a strict range of `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.40` inclusive, with five consecutive statements.

For example:

```
deny  192.168.1.0;
allow 192.168.1.0/27;
allow 192.168.1.32/29;
allow 192.168.1.40;
deny  all;
```

`192.168.1.0/27` represents `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.31` inclusive, with the first address explicitly denied by the previous statement.

`192.168.1.32/29` represents `192.168.1.32` to `192.168.1.39` inclusive.

---

For the range `192.168.1.130` to `192.168.1.190`, start by looking at the binary representation of the last byte:

```
130 = 10000010
190 = 10111110
```

So this can be represented by allowing `10xxxxxx` but first denying `1000000x` and `10111111`.

For example:

```
deny  192.168.1.128/31;
deny  192.168.1.191;
allow 192.168.1.128/26;
deny  all;
```

Comment: if i want to allow from 192.168.1.130 to 192.168.1.190 then, I am still confused